Why doesn't print(i, end=" ") print values not in real time but print(i) does? In Python async function
This example prints in console one number at a time every 0.5 seconds:
import asyncio

async def main():
    i = 0
    while i < 11:
        print(i)
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

This example prints all numbers instantly after 5 seconds:
import asyncio


async def main():
    i = 0
    while i < 11:
        print(i, end=" ") # Edit only this line
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Why?

Use print(i, end=" ", flush=True)
